# ASP.NET MVC Template project does not work out of the box

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

It may be a silly question, I have limited experience in working on MVC projects.
Now I needed to create a brand new Asp.net project. I did the following things:

1. In VS2017 created a new ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) project with framework set to 4.6.1 and "MVC" selected as a project template.
2. Added a new MVC 5 View Page (Razor) page named Test.cshtml.
3. Rebuilt the project.
4. Opened the browser with the following urls and results:

   a.) http://localhost:63984/Test.cshtml
   Got: Server Error in '/' Application.

   b.) http://localhost:63984/Test
   Got: Server Error in '/' Application.

   c.) http://localhost:63984/Test/
   Got: Server Error in '/' Application.

   d.) http://localhost:63984/Test.html
   Got: HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Is there a reason why is it not working out of the box? From what I read the default routing should be working fine.
Is there anything missing?

Thanks, Radek

Comment: "Added a new MVC 5 View Page (Razor) page named Test.cshtml." *where* did you add that? You did not create a new Controller so `/Test` will **never** work. You also cannot request a `.cshtml` file. The template works just fine.

Comment: You created a V.  Now you just need the M and the C.

Comment: I suggest going through some of [the documentation Microsoft provides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started).

Comment: As suggested by Piotr Stapp I have created a Controller, but that does not solve the problem. Also, VS2017 option to create a new Page item should know the type of the project so it shouldn't create items that cannot work out of the box. Don't see the reason to -1 to my question. Adding a new page in MVC by default should create these 3 items automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you created only View. You are missing a controller for serving it (and fill it with data). Add a controller, then add a corresponding view and in the end of the action in the controller return `View("YOUR_VIEW_NAME"`)

Comment: Actually I added a page. I also create a view but no controller. It also does not work, so let me see if adding a controller is working. Quite confusing and complicated.

Comment: Added corresponding controller to a TestView - named it TestController. Now I get another type of error: The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Test/Index.aspx
~/Views/Test/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/Test/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Test/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml

Comment: Check this official tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-view

Comment: @RadekStrugalski Stack Overflow is not for the most basic errors. Please read a MVC tutorial as the one linked.

Comment: @RadekStrugalski the Test.cshtml must be in proper location. For example rename it to Index.cshtml and put it in in /Views/Test or use `View("Test")` to use Test.cshtml

Comment: @RadekStrugalski it is not complicated until you accept the pattern MVC (model-view-controller)

Answer (score 0):

Piotr Stapp was close. The missing detail was that the controller had to have a corresponding view created in a ***subfolder*** with the same name as the controller name.

And yes, adding a Page template for MVC shouldn't even be offered by VS2017. If it is it should create all MVC components correctly bound instead of a garbage which don't even suppose to run. It would be really handy as this is not so simple as it used to be in prior MVC times.

And https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-view is actually a very useful tutorial. Thanks Piotr!